# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock

Tags: java

**My assignment:**

Create a tester that creates two HandGamePlayer objects (default constructor    for cpu full constructor for human), play for 3 rounds by asking the user for a choice of sign (1-5 now), outputting the two players signs, and outputting  who won. Once all rounds are done, output the stats and declare the overall winner!

Been working on this all day, can anyone explain to me how to get the sign symbol to recognize? My professor tried to explain to me what to do but I'm just lost...

This is what he said to do, but I don't even know what it means:

"sign is not declared within main, so it says that the symbol can’t be found.  You generated a hand sign, but printed it out and didn’t store it! Instead make an int sign; variable and store the hand sign there (still print it out, but now you’ll be able to use it in your multi-way if/else)"

Check out my code and let me know if you guys got any ideas.

HandGameTester.java

```
//MAIN
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HandGameTester
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner keyboard;

  HandSign hs;
  int sign;
  int handSign;
  int win = 0;
  int loose = 0;
  int tied = 0;
  int loopCount;

  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  hs = new HandSign();
  hs = sign;

  System.out.println("Pick A Choice Below To Play");
  System.out.println("1: Rock");
  System.out.println("2: Paper");
  System.out.println("3: Scissors");
  System.out.println("4: Lizard");
  System.out.println("5: Spock");

  handSign = keyboard.nextInt(); 

  System.out.println("You chose " + handSign);
  hs.printHandSign(hs.getHandSign());

  if(handSign == sign) {
      System.out.println("You tied!");
      tied++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 1 && sign == 2 || sign == 5) {
      System.out.println("You loose!");
      loose++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 1 && sign == 3 || sign == 4) {
      System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 2 && sign == 1 || sign == 5) {
      System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 2 && sign == 3 || sign == 2) {
      System.out.println("You loose!");
      loose++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 3 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) {
      System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 3 && sign == 3 || sign == 5) {
      System.out.println("You loose!");
      loose++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 4 && sign == 2 || sign == 5) {
      System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
      loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 4 && sign == 3 || sign == 4) {
     System.out.println("You loose!");
     loose++;
     loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 5 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) {
     System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
     loopCount++;
  } else if(handsign == 5 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) {
      System.out.println("You loose!");
      loose++;
      loopCount++;
  } else {
      System.out.println("You win!");
      win++;
      loopCount++;
  } if((win > loose) || (win > tied)) {
      System.out.println("You Win Best Out of Three!");
  } else if(tied > win || tied > loose) {
      System.out.println("You Tied!");
  } else if(loose > win || loose > win) {
      System.out.println("You loose!");
  } else if(win == loose || win == tied) {
      System.out.println("You tied!");
  } else {
      System.out.println("You Win Best Out of Three!");
  }
 }
}
```

HandSign.java

```
public class HandSign
{
 public static final int ROCK = 1;
 public static final int PAPER = 2;
 public static final int SCISSOR = 3;
 public static final int LIZARD = 4;
 public static final int SPOCK = 5;
 public static int getHandSign();

 { 
  return (int)Math.random() * 5;
 }
 public static int printHandSign(int sign)
 {
  switch(sign)
  {
   case 1:
    System.out.println("Rock");
    return sign;
   case 2:
      System.out.println("Paper");
      return sign;
   case 3:
      System.out.println("Scissor");
      return sign;
   case 4:
      System.out.println("Lizard");
      return sign;
   case 5:
      System.out.println("Spock");
      return sign;
   default:
        System.out.println("Fatal Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The concept you need to revisit is "variable assignment".  Your professor is not giving you the answer, he's doing it better, he's trying to teach you how to teach yourself by giving you only the most fuzzy and generic directions possible.  He could have just spoon fed you the answer, but he didn't.  You might want to review how variables work in Java: http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-variables.html  Don't give up, if it were easy, everyone would do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous errors (but mostly unecessary variables) in your code.

I suppose you can tell your professor that he or she was wrong in that `sign` was, in fact, **declared,** but it was not **initialized.** Examine the beginning of your `main()` method. One line simply states,

`int sign;`

This is a **declaration** -- you are telling the program that the `sign` variable exists. However, you are not setting it equal to anything -- you are not **initializing** it.

However, this is certainly not to say that your code is without other flaws.

Firstly, as stated, you never initialized `sign.` As you later set `handSign` equal to the nextInt of a System.in Scanner, we can assume that `handSign` is the user's chosen sign (Either rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spok.) You then compare `handSign` with `sign` and state that, if they are equal to one another, then you tied with the computer. By this we can assume that `sign` is the computer's chosen sign. When your professor told you that you did not store a variable within `sign`, he was dead right! You declared sign, but never made the computer choose what `sign` was -- you never set it equal to anything.

Look at your HandSign class. You created the `getHandSign()` method which returns a random value, but you never called the method!

Secondly, you have a lot of unecessary variables.

Here's what you want to do:

In the main method, get rid of the `hs` variable. Why? Think about it -- there are only two players, and so there will only be two signs. You have three variables for signs -- `hs, handSign, and sign`. You then imply that `handSign` is the user's sign and `sign` is the computer's sign in your if statements. `hs` is not only unecessary, but it is implied that a sign is, in your program, typically an `Integer` while `hs` is of the type `HandSign`. Also, every variable and method within the HandSign class is static, meaning that any instance of the HandSign class is, in essence, useless.

Secondly, you created several constants within your HandSign class, but never used them. You could either get rid of them entirely, or substitute the numbers in the switch statement for the constants. For example, where it says:

`case 1:`

you could (and should) change it to:

`case ROCK:`

You could (and should) do the same thing in your several if / else statements in the HandGameTester `main()` method. (Note that you would have to reference the constants via the HandSign class -- `HandSign.ROCK`, etc.)

Finally, and most importantly, initialize the `sign` variable!

You created the static method which generates a random value between 1 and 5, but never called it, so call it:

`int sign = HandSign.getHandSign();`

This will call the `getHandSign()` method and set `sign` equal to the returned random value between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have never remembered the sign generated by getHandSign. You call

```
hs.printHandSign(hs.getHandSign());
```

Which prints out the sign the computer generated, but you never remembered this sign in a variable.

You appear to have have a variable for this you just never give it a value.

```
int sign; // defaults to zero as you have not given it a value
...
hs = new HandSign();
hs = sign; // This line wont compile. 
...
if(handSign == sign) { // sign still has no value set so is still the default of zero.
```

You should be assigning a value to sign before doing your `if...else if...`. That assignment should look something like

```
sign = ????;
```

With the question marks replaced by a valid integer expression.

Answer (score 0):

> "sign is not declared within main, so it says that the symbol can’t be found.

It looks like you added this with
        `int sign;`

> You generated a hand sign, but printed it out and didn’t store it! Instead make an int sign; variable and store the hand sign there (still print it out, but now you’ll be able to use it in your multi-way if/else)"

What this means is that you have two `HandSign` variables, one that you generate (`hs`) and another you are reading in from the user (`sign`).  However, `sign` is an int and `hs` isn't.  So you need to get an int from `HandSign` by calling `HandSign.getHandSign()` to get the one from the computer player.

Answer (score 0):

Some other posters have commented but I'll just add my 2 cents. There are a few problems I can see immediately.

- There is no loop in main (unless I'm hallucinating) which means that
  only one round will be played.
- It would be nice for user interface if you printed out the computer's choice.
- You've misspelled "lose" as "loose" which makes the code harder to
  read.
- Blank lines appear in the wrong places, or not at all, which also
  makes the code hard to read and debug.
- Huge problem: (int)Math.random() * 5 doesn't do what you want it to
  do. Just create a small program that prints the result of that
  calculation 10 times and you'll see. You need more parentheses, and also
  you need to add 1 because you started counting at 1 instead of 0.
  Alternatively, you could start counting at 0 instead, which (IMHO) is
  better.
- You exit with a fatal error with System.exit(0) but if it really is
  an error the argument should be > 0, e.g., System.exit(1).

In addition, I agree with the other posters. However, it shouldn't be too hard to fix, really just a few minutes. Most of the hard work is done.